# Laravel creating a relationship out of an view - best practice?

Tags: laravel, view, relationship

I defined a relationship
Author - Book

then i am able to create a new book by doing this

```
$author = new author();
$author->books()->create();
```

that works and also doing this in my view

```
{{$author->books()->create()}}
```

So every time the site is loaded i create a new book. I try to embed it in a small script with a button.

```
<button onclick="addBook()">Add new book</button>

<p id="addBook"></p>

<script>
function addBook() {
  document.getElementById("addBook").innerHTML = {{$author->books()->create()}};
}
</script>
```

The Script is loaded on pageload and of course executed without neccesary pressed the button.

What is the best practise?
Is this an intended way to do such?
Or should i better make an POST call out of an form and handle the creation in the controller?

Comment: In your case - you create book on preparing html, but not onClick. So the better way - create post request and Controller

Comment: It is very bad practice to keep in view file anything else than showing data. Any kind of backend logic having in view is anti-pattern. Even if there is need for dynamic change of shown data, at least AJAX call should be used but again all logic that communicate with DB should be in controller or in some file of deeper level (i.e. service, repository, entity, etc).

Answer (score 0):

you cant do this. when code get to `document.getElementById("addBook").innerHTML = {{$author->books()->create()}};` line, auto created book and dont wait for javascript method. you need api to do this, actually you should create a route called book/create and send ajax request with jquery or more libraries after click

Answer (score 0):

It's better to do this in controller, and it's not correct to use the eloquent query in view,
It's better to use Ajax or JavaScript to call an API  like:

```
$.post( "{{route('route.name')}}", { /*object you want to create*/  } );
```